# R CMD CHECK "Found the following assignments to the global environment:"

Tags: r, global-variables

Running `R CMD check` on my package I'm receiving the following warning message:

```
Found the following assignments to the global environment:
File ‘SciencesPo/R/describe.R’:
  assign(as.character(substitute(data)), dataset, pos = 1)
```

I tried to silence it by adding an environment as mentioned [here](http://www.talkstats.com/showthread.php/38050-CRAN-submission-problem-help-brainstorming) using `envir = .SciencesPoEnv`, and `envir = .GlobalEnv`, but received the same message.

**Does anyone have a clue how can I fix it?**

Comment: Packages aren't supposed to assign values to the global environment.  try including the dataset in your package data instead and call `data(myData)` instead.  See [this page](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/data.html) for details on including data in your package

Comment: Your commentary doesn't seem to line up with your code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should do:

```
#' function loading results in global environment
#' @param pos defaults to 1 which equals an assingment to global environment
assign_to_global <- function(pos=1){
  assign("sentence", "That was easy.", envir=as.environment(pos) )
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but I still got the pesky NOTE: `Found the following assignments to the global environment:`.  Did you try anything else that might've worked for you?

Comment: This might be a bit late but this would get one through R CMD check:


`
# global env set hack
(function(key, val, pos) assign(key,val, envir=as.environment(pos)))(myKey, myVal, 1L)
`