# How can I solve the following note returned by `devtools::check()`: `Found the following assignments to the global environment`

Tags: r, package, environment, assign

I haven't found a way to fix the following note that keeps coming up when I execute `devtools::check()` on my package.

```
checking R code for possible problems ... NOTE
  Found the following assignments to the global environment:
  File ‘rrclust/R/infrastructure.R’:
    assign(x, value, envir = globalenv())
    assign(oname, z, envir = globalenv())
```

I tried to replace `globalenv()` by `.GlobalEnv`, but the same note comes up. This question is related to this [closed question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28180989/r-cmd-check-found-the-following-assignments-to-the-global-environment). @Jthorpe suggests to "include the dataset in the package data instead", but this is not possible for me, as the data is changing at each iteration and I need this assignment to be executed during the whole workflow and for each module being run.

Comment: Your workflow seems to be flawed. A package should never assign into the global environment. In fact, no R function should assign into the global environment. I think it sometimes can be OK to assign into the package namespace environment but you should probably redesign your whole approach to comply with better practices.

Comment: In your package create an environment for its own use.  For example create a `zzz.R` file and include a line `MyPackageEnv <- new.env()`  and then use that.  The lattice package creates `LatticeEnv` that way and accesses it using `assign` and the `lattice.options` function.  See https://cran.r-project.org/package=lattice for the source.